# How to highlight-string and unhighlight-string in buffer -- make-overlay

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm presently combing `isearch.el` to find out how to `highlight-string` and `unhighlight-string` in the buffer.  This is needed when `highlight-regexp` will not work -- e.g., a string like this:

```
** Active [#A] .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; HIGH ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;. :HIGH:
   DEADLINE: <2013-12-15 Sun>
```

The functions `isearch-highlight (beg end)` and `isearch-dehighlight` are almost exactly what is needed -- I just need to modify `(beg end)` so that a string can be used.

`beg` and `end` may move during the function (e.g., `org-archive-subtree`), so it is a few extra lines of code to find the string again and re-define `beg` and `end` -- it would be nice to just use something like `(highlight-string string).`

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  In what way does `highlight-regexp` "not work"?  What is the spec for your hypothetical `highlight-string`?  Is it something more than `(highlight-regexp (reqgexp-quote string))`?

Comment: @Drew  I learned something knew today thanks to you -- I hadn't seen `(highlight-regexp (regexp-quote string))` before.  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: You're welcome. People sometimes forget that a literal string ***is*** a regexp, so that functions that work with regexps also work with literal strings. And `regexp-opt` makes a string literal, as a regexp.  I posted the info as an answer, for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `(highlight-regexp (regexp-quote YOUR-STRING))`, to escape all regexp-special characters in `YOUR-STRING`.